# Regular Expressions Question

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have this program:

```
        Dim words() As String = {"car", "arc", "caar"}

        For Each w In words
            Dim rx = Regex.IsMatch("rca", "^[" + w + "]+$")
            Console.WriteLine(rx)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
```

This Regex `"^[" + w + "]+$"` finds all words which consists of letters "rca". This matches for all words, because all words are made up from "rca". Is there something I could add, to return False for "caar", because "rca" has only one "a", but "caar" has two "a"?

Comment: You are building the regex out of the words and not the other way round as I think it should be: `Regex.IsMatch(w, "^[rca]+$")`. In your case the word `oscar` would also match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it e.g. with the following regular expression:

```
"(?=^[^r]*r[^r]*$)(?=^[^c]*c[^c]*$)(?=^[^a]*a[^a]*$)^[rca]+$"
```

It matches any word consisting of letters "rca" but each one at exactly once.

**Addon**: if the condition is "at most once" you can instead use

```
"(?=^[^r]*r?[^r]*$)(?=^[^c]*c?[^c]*$)(?=^[^a]*a?[^a]*$)^[rca]+$"
```

Comment: This works! Is it possible to change this expression to allow for "ca", "ra", "ar","r","c" and "a", by using '?' somewhere?

Comment: +1 This is pretty clever. It gets disproportionally unmanageable the more letters you want to match, but for three letters it is still okay.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, you're right. But I don't think that regex is the right tool for such tasks - especially if there are much more letters involved ;-)

Comment: @Howard How to update this expression to return "caar" if I enter "rcaa"?

Comment: @Cobold I don't understand your question. Why "caar"? Why not "rcaa" or "raac"? Regex are used for matching. Not for sorting characters.

Comment: @Howard It doesn't matter. The question is, if I had words in the list, which has more than one instance of a single letter, like in words good, apple, eye and others, then how to return true for them?

Comment: "(?=^[^g]*g?[^g]*$)(?=^[^o]*o?[^o]*$)(?=^[^o]*o?[^o]*$)(?=^[^d]*d?[^d]*$)^[good]+$" doesn't return True for word "good".

Comment: @Cobold it then gets more and more complex. You'll have to use "(?=^[^g]*g?[^g]*$)(?=^[^o]*(o?[^o]*){2}$)(?=^[^d]*d?[^d]*$)^[god]‌​+$" for any word with zero or one g, zero to two o and zero to one d. But once again: you shold not use regex for such tasks. Instead sort the characters of both strings and then compare them directly. Or count the occurence of each char in each string and compare those numbers.

Comment: @Howard, Very clever. Unfortunately clever in the bad way. As you said, it is far better to simply sort the letters and compare directly. Probably faster too considering the exponential complexity of the regex.

Answer (score 3):

> This Regex `"^[" + w + "]+$"` finds all words which consists of letters `"rca"`

No, it does not. It searches the string `"rca"` for all the letters that happen to be in `w`

What you *mean* (given that your plain English explanation reflects what you want) is:

```
Dim rx = Regex.IsMatch(w, "^[rca]+$")
```

*You could change `+` to `{3}`, but this would still match `aaa`.

To match any *permutation* of three letters, you would have to add permutations yourself. Regex can't do this for you.

```
Dim rx = Regex.IsMatch(w, "^rca|rac|acr|arc|car|cra$")
```

Comment: This would not help me, because I could change the letters to "rca" and the word list.

Comment: @Cobold: *What* would not help you? The fact that I told you you'd have do create the permutations manually? I did not say that you'd have to hard-code it all. But *"How do I get every permutation of a string in VB.NET?"* is material for a separate question, actually.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do it separately, outside the regex. The `[...]` construct always treats repeated characters as if they were entered once. You could do something like this right before the `Console.WriteLine(rx)` (note: writing in C# because I'm not very current in VB):

```
foreach (var ch in w.ToCharArray())
{
    if (w.Count(c => c == ch) != "rca".Count(c => c == ch))
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it looks like you're using the words as the pattern to search for, perhaps you mean:

```
Dim rx = Regex.IsMatch(w, "^[rca]+$")
```

In order to filter out words that contain only one of the letters in your pattern (`rca`), you might try:

```
^[^rca]*[rca][^rca]*$
```

This will match

```
"anything not r, c or a" zero or many times; 
"r, c or a"; 
"anything not r, c or a" zero or many times;
```